# magento programmatically get the shipping tax from an order

Tags: php, magento

how can i programmatically get the shipping tax from an order increment_id in magento?

I try this script, but seems not to work.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("increment_id");
$taxRefunded = $order->getTaxRefunded();
```

Thanks

Comment: Questions about Magento are best asked on [magento.se]

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve tax information from order with following code, returning an array.
You can parse and use this array to get the shipping tax ammount.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', 100000166)->getFirstItem();
$taxRefunded = $order->getFullTaxInfo();
var_dump($taxRefunded);
```

E.g.: to retrieve tax percent:

```
$tax_percent = $taxRefunded[0]['percent'];
```